# NextJS: Hydration Error when loading page

Tags: typescript, next.js, deployment

I am writing a personal website in next to learn a bit about NextJS and web development. I am writing this site in TypeScript. I am trying to have a page that dynamically generates cards based on markdown files inside a `public/projects` directory. Here is the code that I am currently using:

```js
import { getAllProjectIds, getProjectData } from "@/lib/projects";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";

export default async function Projects() {
    const projects = getAllProjectIds();

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <ul className={styles.projects}>
                {projects.map(async (project, index) => {
                    const data: any = await getProjectData(project.params.id);
                    return (
                        <li key={index} className={styles.project}>
                            <Image 
                                src={`/projects${data.image}`} 
                                width={0} 
                                height={0} 
                                sizes="100vw" 
                                style={{width: "50%", height: "auto"}}
                                alt={data.image}/>
                        </li>
                )})}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the contents of `lib/projects.ts`:

```js
import { readFileSync, readdirSync } from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import path from "path";
import rehypeParse from "rehype-parse";
import remarkHtml from "remark-html";
import remarkParse from "remark-parse";
import { unified } from "unified";

const projectsPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/projects');

export function getAllProjectIds() {
    const files = readdirSync(projectsPath, { withFileTypes: true});

    return files.filter(file => file.isFile()).map((file) => {
        return {
            params: {
                id: file.name.replace(/\.md$/, ''),
            },
        };
    });
}

export async function getProjectData(id: string) {
    const fullPath = path.join(projectsPath, `${id}.md`);
    const fileContents = readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf-8');

    const matterRes = matter(fileContents);

    const remarkRes = await unified()
        .use(remarkParse)
        .use(remarkHtml)
        .process(matterRes.content);
    const rawHTML = remarkRes.toString();

    return {
        id,
        rawHTML,
        ...matterRes.data,
    };
}
```

I have tried to use client side rendering, but I am using `fs` for `/lib/projects.ts` which only works on the server. When I go to the page it loads and displays what I expected, however I get 3 errors in little next error box:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

```
TypeError: parentNode is null
```

and

```
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```